# Creating individual reports

Tags: reporting

I was trying to create some reports with telerik. Now the problem is, that the columns for every report are different. I can’t make a report pattern for each individual situation because the definition is configured individually by the customer on a website for every report request. And the data for the report is very nested with multiple data source tables. So with the on-board features I can’t solve the problem. I would have to create the Reports per program code. The telerik api is very complex, so I think it is a much easier way to create the reports in html, before using a reporting engine.

Now the question? Does anyone have an idea, if there is a better way to create these highly individual reports then create it directly in html or using a report engine?

Answer (score 0):

By what you describe, i believe you need a report engine that let your end users design their reports, if i'm right, then these questions may help you: [jQuery plugin for designing report layouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1845558/jquery-plugin-for-designing-report-layouts), [HTML 5 report designer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20649569/html-5-report-designer), [I need to code a dynamic report builder in ASP.NET, where should I start?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14076268/i-need-to-code-a-dynamic-report-builder-in-asp-net-where-should-i-start/14076394#14076394)